# About tarjan's algorithm for finding scc

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, tarjans-algorithm

I'm a senior student learing informatics olympiad on algorithms, and this is my first question on stackoverflow.

In tarjan's dfs search getting *lowlink(u)*:

`low[u]=min(low[u],low[v])` (v isn't visited)

or

`low[u]=min(low[u],dfn[v])` (v is still in the stack)

My question is, is it still ok to **replace *dfn[v]* for *low[v]* in the second case**? I know this is incorrect, but I failed finding a counter-example. Could anyone help explain this?

thx:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, actually.

The proof of correctness depends on two properties of `low`. The first is that, for all `v`, there exists `w` reachable from `v` such that `dfn[w] <= low[v] <= dfn[v]`. The second is that, when determining whether `v` is a root, we have for all `w` reachable from `v` that `low[v] <= dfn[w]`.

We can prove inductively that the first property still holds by the fact that, if there's a path from `u` to `v` and a path from `v` to `w`, then there's a path from `u` to `w`. As for the second, let `low` be the original array and `low'` be yours. It's not hard to show that, for all `v`, at all times, `low'[v] <= low[v]`, so at the critical moment for `v`, for all `w` reachable from `v`, it holds that `low'[v] <= low[v] <= dfn[w]`.

I imagine that the algorithm is presented the way it is to avoid the need to consider intermediate values of `low`.